# Как проверить существует ли картинка, и если нет, то вывести другую

Tags: laravel

Как в laravel проверить существует ли картинка по внешней ссылке, если нет то показать другую?

И включая проверка картинки не только внешней, но и на собственном сервере.

Вывод в шаблоне такой:

```
<img src="{{ $post->logo }}"> // в ней ссылка такого вида: https://website.ru/photos/959892.png
```

Если картинки не существует то вывести `https://website.ru/photos/no-photo.png`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если с каталога public:

```
if (File::exists('img/test.png')) {}
```

Если с каталога storage:

```
if (Storage::exists('public/test.png)) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ImageUrlController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke($path_file)
    {
        if(Storage::exists('/public/images/'.$path_file)){
            $image_path=response()->file(Storage::path('/public/images/'.$path_file));
        }else {
            $image_path=response()->file(Storage::path('/public/images/default.jpg'));
        }

        return $image_path;
    }
}
```

[детальніше тут: ларавел посилання на зоображення](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-s1a6yFyy4)

Comment: пожалуйста, переведите (нажав [edit]) текст ответа на русский язык.